Difference between ~だの~だの and other structures
I would like to know if the structure ~だの~だの and the structures ~がどうの~がこうの and ~がどうとか~がこうとか are the three of them totally interchangeable or they have some differences in meaning or any different nuance in usage. If it's the latter, could you please explain me those differences?
I can barely find much information about the structures ~がどうの~がこうの and ~がどうとか~がこうとか nor examples of how are they used in any grammar site or corpus, so if you could also give me examples of how you would use them or see them used, it would help me a lot. I guess somewhat they may be similar to ~だの~だの by some results I could find on Google, but I'm not sure at all.
Thank you very much in advance for any help you can give me.

If you say:

田中だの山下だの

The speaker is referring to the fact that somebody is suggesting names (usually implying there were more suggestions than the two named), in a dismissing manner. E.g. 「田中だの山下だの色んな名前がでてくるが、俺は責任者が誰なのか知りたい」 means the speaker is frustrated that the conversation partner is listing many names but aren't giving out the info the speaker wants.

田中がどうの、山下がこうの

Here the speaker is referring what is said about Tanaka and Yamashita (how they are, what they did etc.) in a similarly dismissive manner. E.g. 「田中がどうの、山下がこうのと言い訳はいいから解決策を考えろ」would mean the conversation partner is explaining why something happened (maybe referring to what Tanaka/Yamashita did, said, or are thinking), but the speaker wants them to stop and focus on providing solutions.

田中がどうとか山下がこうとか

This is very similar to the other example and can be interchanged. But technically it emphasises how the speaker is referring to other things said by the conversation partner as well. It's a bit like adding etc. but more subtle (as in, it's not 100% clear if the speaker is thinking of some other concrete thing they are referring to, but they could be).

First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I appreciate a lot your help. :)

If I understood correctly, sharing the three structures the dismissive tone, ~だの~だの refers more to suggestions and could be translated seeing your example as "like A and B" (names like Tanaka and Yamashita), whereas ~がどうの~がこうの and ~がどうとか~がこうとか point more clearly A and B (among others). Am I right?

However, as for how to use it, I'm still not sure how to do it in a real situation. If possible, could you please put your examples into some context so that I can imagine a certain situation and see in what concrete case I could use those structures? I'm very sorry for the trouble, but if you could please do so, it would help me a lot.
